# Creating a JavaScript Search of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, text

I'm new to these forums and very new to JavaScript. Since my school does not offer in depth JavaScript courses, I have tried to understand a lot of it on my own.

This may be a basic question but basically I want to create 2 arrays. The first array will have a host of 'id' numbers. The second array will have price numbers. I want it so when a user enters in those id numbers in a text box it will output the values of the price array numbers in another text box.

Here's sort of an example using prompts:

```
noArray = new Array(3);
noArray[1]="03";
noArray[2]="12";
noArray[3]="15";
nameArray = new Array(3);
nameArray[1] = "$45";
nameArray[2] = "$300";
nameArray[3] = "$900";

var userNumIn=prompt("Enter the item number you want to retrieve","");
var itemSub=1;
var matchInd= false;

while (itemSub <= 3 && matchInd == false){
    if (noArray[itemSub] == userNumIn){
        matchInd = true;
    } else {
        itemSub++ ;
    }
}

if (matchInd == true){
    document.write("The item costs " + nameArray[itemSub]);
} else {
    document.write("Invalid item number");
}
```

The question is how do I compare the value of what someone typed in the an "id" textbox with the id array and then if that value matches, have it check the price array for the price of that id and then output to a 'price' textbox? I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: The `document.write()` facility is kind-of a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Array indexes start from 0, so both `noArray` looks like `[ , "03", "12", "15"]` (and similarly for `nameArray`): you should be assigning to `noArray[0]`, `noArray[1]`, `noArray[2]`. And also, Javascript has [`true` and `false`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/boolean.html), which you should use instead of `"Y"` and `"N"`.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about objects.

Basically, objects are a mapping between strings and some value, which seems to be what you want. Your code is much simpler if you use objects. Look at how you don't need to use any sort of looping or any auxiliary variables.

```
var prices = {
  "03": "$45",
  "12": "$300",
  "15": "$900"
};
var id = prompt("Enter the item number you want to retrieve","");

if(id in prices) {
  alert("The item costs " + prices[id]);
}
else {
  alert("Invalid item number");
}
```

[You can see this in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KexHq/).

You specifically asked about using a textbox and a button, so I created an example page of how you can do that. First, you need an HTML form

```
ID: <input id="input" type="text"/><br>
<button id="submit">Get Price</button><br>
Price: <output id="output"/>
```

and then you just slightly modify the Javascript above to make the form work

```
var prices = {
    "03": "$45",
    "12": "$300",
    "15": "$900"
};

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
    var id = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var price = id in prices ? prices[id] : "Invalid ID";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = price;
};
```

And [you can see this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/KexHq/1/)

Comment: I have a question about your code. You use an *in* argument in the variable prices. Exactly how does that work? Thanks a lot for making a working example as well. Very helpful.

Comment: @Brian The `in` is just the Javascript keyword that checks if an object contains a certain property.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up code, though don't expect users to do this in the future...

```
2dArray = new Array(3)(2)
2dArray[0][0] = "03";
2dArray[0][1] = "$45";
2dArray[1][0] = "12";
2dArray[1][1] = "$300";
2dArray[2][0] = "15";
2dArray[2][1] = "$900";

var userNumIn=prompt("Enter the item number you want to retrieve","");
var matchInd = false;

for(var i = 0; i < 3 && !matchInd; i++){
    if (2dArray[i][0] == userNumIn){
        matchInd = true;
        document.getElementById('yourTextBoxId').value = 2dArray[i][1];
    }
}

if(!matchInd) {
    document.getElementById('yourTextBoxId').value = "Invalid item number";
}
```

I just needed a javascript refresh ^^ didn't test, hope it works. If anything is unclear just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is sound and will work once you incorporate the things that dbaupp mentions. Here is a more advanced but cleaner way to do it:

In JavaScript you are free to create objects that take any shape you want. So you can define objects that contain both the item's number and its price. For example:

```
var item = {
    number: '03',
    price: '$45'
};
```

Now item is an object containing both things about item number 03:

```
alert(item.number); // alerts 03
alert(item.price);  // alerts $45
```

You can stick objects in arrays, so instead of two arrays, it's better to have one array that contains everything you need

```
var itemArray = new Array(3);
// note the first index in array is 0, not 1
itemArray[0] = {
    number: '03',
    price: '$45'
};
itemArray[1] = {
    number: '12',
    price: '$300'
};
itemArray[2] = {
    number: '15',
    price: '$900'
};
```

Now it is easier to find the item the user wants:

```
var userNumIn = prompt("Enter the item number you want to retrieve","");

for(var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; ++i) {
    var item = itemArray[i];
    if(item.number === userNumberIn) {
        alert("The item costs " + item.price);
    }
}
```

There is still many ways this can be improved. I purposely only introduced objects to keep the changes simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt Greer. Learning about objects and the suggestions people have made about 'true or false' boolean JS values _will_ make things way easier in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Javascript object as hashtables to simplify the logic.

Objects in Javascript can be used as a hashtable, so, when you perform a lookup, the runtime will be O(1), instead of looping through an array, which is a O(n).

```
// Restructure the array so it's in a very simple
// 'hashtable' - Key: id, value: price.
// Lookup time on this is O(1)
var priceLookup = {
    "03" : "$45",    // I assume the 0 is important
    "12" : "$300",
    "15" : "$900"
};

// Get data from user
var id = prompt('Enter item ID');

// Check if item exists in the price lookup
if (priceLookup[id]) {
    // Alert user with price
    document.write("The item costs " + priceLookup[id]);
}
else {
    // ID is invalid in this case.
    document.write("Invalid item number");
}
​
​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C4RLV/

Comment: Hash tags, I've heard about them before but never really knew what they were. That really makes things a lot easier. It seems I have much to learn still! Thanks!

Comment: @Brian - It's actually hashtable/hashmap. Here's a Wiki article to it that may explain more... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table It's a very useful data structure if you've to do a lot of lookup!